# basic php array from loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

im trying to create an array from a loop in PHP.

I want the array to end up something like $array(100,100,100,100), this is my code:

```
$x = 0; 
while($x < 5){ 
$array[$x] = 100; 
$x++; 
} 

echo $array[0];
```

It outputs 1 instead of 100.
Can someone tell me where i'm going wrong.

Comment: For me, copy/pasted straight into the PHP interpreter it works correctly. PHP 5.3.8

Comment: Works like a charm for me: http://codepad.org/9U8Yfqfp. Are you sure that the `$array` is empty before inserting the new values?

Comment: A for loop would be more appropriate than while here `for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++)` since you know both the starting and ending values of `$x`. i.e. since you have a predetermined number of iterations.

Answer (score 5):

Even though it works perfectly for me, you should be initialising the variable beforehand.

```
$array = array();
```

For example, if `$array` is non-empty string, you will see the output of `1`.

Comment: could you explain why it happens with the non empty string? I could imagine that it results in `11111` by casting 100 to string and taking the first char, but can't imagine why it is `1`.

Comment: @NikiC - It's because it's setting a character in the string, and not a new array value, and `$array[0]` will be the first "character" in the string; see my second demo.

Comment: ah, got it, $array[0] is output, so it takes only the first 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the predefined [`array_fill`](http://php.net/array_fill) function for that:

```
$array = array_fill(0, 5, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers pretty much cover this. I would, however, recommend you use a for loop for this instead of a while loop if you're going to use a loop rather than a function to do it.

```
$array = array();
for($x=0; $x<5; $x++) {
    $array[$x] = 100;
}
```

In fact, you could make this even shorter.

```
$array = array();
for($x=0; $x<5; $array[$x++]=100);
```

It's perfectly valid to have a for loop statement instead of a block. And blocks can go anywhere too; they don't need an if statement, for loop, while loop, or whatever, before them.